# Can't resize an image HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, resize

I can't resize an image in css/html.
Here's my code I can't resize it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DoYouLoveDogs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<body>
<div id="top">
<div class="img-yes">
    <img class="img-yes" src="img/yes.png">
</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
</div>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/button.js"></script>
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my css:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#top{
    background-color: #53FF40;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
#bottom{
    background-color: #FF5757;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.img-yes{
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

ok so that's it.
And one more question where can I learn php.
I want  to build a social network.

Comment: how big do you want it?

Comment: For starters...  you shouldn't be sharing the same class name on the `img` tag and the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Try min-width and min-height for image. Div also has same class so it will effect twice. There are lots of online php documents on internet. Just "google" what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Please try give absolute size with correct aspect ratio to resize or you can use bootstrap responsive tag img-responsive to resize based on viewport.

Check w3cschools for PHP tutorial.

Comment: Create a class for div and specify its max-width, and then create another class for image and set its max-width as 100%. That way your image is contained inside the constrained size of its div....

.imagedivclass{max-width=800px;}
.imageclass{max-width=100%;}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#top{
    background-color: #53FF40;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
#bottom{
    background-color: #FF5757;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50%;
}
.img-yes{
    min-width: 25%;
    min-height: 25%;
}
```

or you can set specific width to your image container like **width:500px;**

Comment: widht: 500px; works but i want to size in percentage for mobile

Comment: @1234filip as far as i know you will have to give a specific width to your container div before you can use %